# Set "Select" option for all checked rows in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Still learning jquery here, so forgive any ignorance.

I have a table that contains a number of rows. Each row has a `<select>` tag and I want to "toggle" its value when I execute a function. So here's what the table looks like for example:

```
<table align="center" class="table table-bordered table-hover table-condensed table-responsive">
  <thead>
    ...
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="text-center"><input id="item_ids_" name="item_ids[]" type="checkbox" value="11521"></td>
      <td class="text-center">Item value here</td>
      <td class="text-center">
        <select class="form-control" id="item_11521_color" name="item[11521][color]">
          <option selected="selected" value="None">None</option>
          <option value="Blue">Blue</option>
          <option value="Orange">Orange</option>
          <option value="Green">Green</option>
          <option value="Yellow">Yellow</option>
          <option value="Purple">Purple</option>
        </select>
      </td>
      <td class="text-center">
        <select class="form-control" id="item_11521_test" name="item[11521][test]">
          <option selected="selected" value="None">None</option>
          <option value="First">First</option>
          <option value="Second">Second</option>
        </select>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

How can I iterate through each row and change the value (and text) `<option value="Blue">` to `<option value="Orange">` etc each time I run this function?

Comment: Please add more details explaining exactly what you expect this function to do.

Comment: Simply change the first group of "options" for all rows that are selected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for? (code updated)

```
$("#change").on("click", function() {

    // loop throw all rows
    $("table tr").each(function() {

        // on a row, find the checkbox and change the values if it's checked
        if($(this).find("input[type='checkbox']").prop("checked")) {
            $(this).find(".color-select").val("Green");
            $(this).find(".position-select").val("First");
        } 

    });

});
```

Added a button to perform the change:

```
<button id="change">change all to Green and first</button>
```

And classes to the selects for simplicity:

```
<select class="form-control color-select" id="item_11521_color" name="item[11521 [color]">
<select class="form-control position-select" id="item_11521_test" name="item[11521][test]">
```

**EDIT:**

Made required changes to the code.

The updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/theagitator/44vqugf0/1/

Comment: Sort of. But the checkboxes in the jsfiddle demo doesn't determine what rows are modified. This is something I'm looking to do. Very close though. Thanks

Comment: So if the option wasn't already the one it was changed to, then the checkbox should on the row should be checked? I'm struggling to make sense what you are going for here.

Comment: I have a table containing several rows. I want to "mass change" each row's (if checkbox is checked) "Blue" option to "Orange".

Comment: That's exactly what my code is doing. If you don't want to change the other select, just don't use that part of the code.

Comment: Oh ok. Now I understand.

Comment: yep!! so if no rows are checked and you click the button, nothing should get changed. if i select the checkbox for row 1 and hit the button, then the option gets changed for row 1 only, etc.